# How can I set a div size based on the device screen size?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web app to be used on iOS devices, both iPhone4 and iPhone5.  I developed the app using a 5 and everything fits and works perfectly, but trying to get it to fit the smaller height of a 4 doesn't seem to work.  Here's what I'm looking to accomplish:

[image: layout of divs]

I have a header div at the top, a title div that holds an image and the date, then a list div, followed by a footer div.  All are contained within a div named container.  I want  the header, title, and footer divs to remain fixed, and the list div to scroll the content that's dynamically fed into it on load.  The footer should remain at the bottom of the screen and the list should scroll out from under it (if that makes sense).

I set fixed heights for all the divs when developing this and it works on my iPhone5, but when I try to set the list div height as ((window.screen.height) - header - title - footer) the entire document scrolls, rather than just the list div.  Here's what I've created through much trial and error:

```
#container {
    min-width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
}

#title {
    height: 330px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#list {
    height: 1592px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#footer {
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Media Queries?

Comment: Can you please provide Jsfiddle....

Comment: I looked into that a bit last night but didn't try it. Would I want to have separate style sheets for each device in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use fixed positionings, plus, instead of specifying the height of `#list` use top and bottom to make it fit.

```
#container {
    min-width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    posiotion:fixed;
    top:0px; /* Top left corner of the screen */
    left:0px;
}

#title {
    height: 330px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    posiotion:fixed;
    top:140px; /* 140px below the top left corner of the screen */
    left:0px;
}

#list {
    /*height: 1592px; remove this - the height will be determined by top and bottom */
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    posiotion:fixed;
    top:470px; /* start 470px below top left corner */
    bottom:140px; /* This is the trick - specify bottom instead of height */
    left:0px;

}

#footer {
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    posiotion:fixed;
    top:auto;
    bottom:0px; /* Stick to bottom */
    left:0px;
}
```

Note: from your code I understand `#title` should not be scrolled. If you want it to scroll as well put it inside `#list` and update the positions.